# R function persp(): Is there a way to generate a log scale?

Tags: r, plot, 3d

Is it possible to put the following on a log-scale?

```
x <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 50)  
y <- x  
rotsinc <- function(x,y) {
  sinc <- function(x) { y <- sin(x)/x ; y[is.na(y)] <- 1; y }  
  10 * sinc( sqrt(x^2+y^2) )  
}
persp(x,y,z,ticktype = "detailed")
```

Comment: The code isn't reproducible (gives error, object `z` not found)

Comment: oops sorry i missed defining z...

z <- outer(x, y, rotsinc)